# Elegant way to append string that not null

Tags: java, string, oop

I have a class that contains some attributes and I want to concatenate the attribute if the value is not null. What is the elegant way to do it? What I have done so far is something like this (in `combine` method).

```
public class X {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e;
    private int f;
    private Date g;

    public String combine() {
        String result = "";
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.a)) {
            result += a + "\n";
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.b)) {
            result += b + "\n";
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.c)) {
            result += c + "\n";
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.d)) {
            result += d + "\n";
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.e)) {
            result += e + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Don't use the `Date` class, as it's obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in `toString` method by using java-8 `stream`

```
Stream.of(this.getA(),this.getB(),this.getC(),this.getD(),this.getE())
      .filter(str->!StringUtils.isEmpty(str))
      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

or you can use `StringUtils. isNotEmpty`

```
 Stream.of(this.getA(),this.getB(),this.getC(),this.getD(),this.getE())
      .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use streams:

```
return Stream.of(a, b, c, d, e)
    .filter(str -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(str))
    .map(str -> str + "\n")
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

This first filters out all of the strings which are empty, then appends a `\n` to each element, and at last concatenates all pieces into a string.

Note that instead of the `map` and `collect` methods, you could also use `collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))` (see Deadpool's answer), but then note that the last element is not followed by a newline. So you need to append it to the result yourself.

Also note that, as YCF_L said in the comments, you could replace `filter(str -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(str))` by the method reference `.filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)`, leveraging the fact that the `StringUtils` class offers the inverse of `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream.

```
Stream.of(this.a, this.b, this.c, this.d, this.e)
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
            .map(str -> str + "\n")
            .collect(Collectors.joining())
```